How to create a list of elements of an indexed data type, whose length depends on the index
I am busy formalising a theorem using a library which introduces an indexed datatype. For simplicity one can think of it to have the form data idx (n : ℕ).
Now I want to create a list of elements over this datatype with the parameter fixed, whose length depends on this parameter. I have simplified the whole problem to the example below:
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ ; _+_ ; suc ; zero) public
open import Data.List.Base using (_∷_ ; [] ; List) public

data idx (n : ℕ) : Set where
  num : ℕ → idx n

exampleA : List (idx 4) -- some random list
exampleA = num 12312 ∷ num 4792384 ∷ []

exampleB : List (idx 4) -- list of the form that I want
exampleB = num 1 ∷ num 2 ∷ num 3 ∷ num 4 ∷ []

rev-list : (m n : ℕ) → List (idx (n + m))
rev-list zero n = []
-- I want to put "m" in the first hole and "suc n" in the second hole,
-- but I get the following errors:
-- first hole:  m !=< suc m of type ℕ
-- second hole: suc (n + ?0) !=< n + suc m of type ℕ
rev-list (suc m) n = num (suc m) ∷ rev-list {!!} {!!} 

rev-list' : (m n : ℕ) → List (idx (n + m))
rev-list' m zero = []
-- I want to put "n" in the hole, but I get the following error:
-- n + suc m !=< suc (n + m) of type ℕ
rev-list' m (suc n) =  num (suc n) ∷ rev-list' (suc m) {!!}

I want to write a function func : (m n : ℕ) → List (idx (n + m)) that returns a list num 1 ∷ num 2 ∷ num 3 ∷ num 4 ∷ ... num (n + m) ∷ [] when called with func 0 (n + m) or maybe func (n + m) 0 - whatever would work - (as in exampleB).
It seems to be simpler to first compute the reverse list, which I try to achieve in rev-list and rev-list'.
However, I get the errors indicated in the code above. I have been struggling with this for hours to no avail. If anybody here could help me, it would be much appreciated :)

Given that the parameter is fixed you can simply do
open import Data.List.Base using (tabulate)
open import Data.Fin.Base using (toℕ)
open import Function using (_∘_)

func : (m n : ℕ) → List (idx (n + m))
func m n = tabulate {n = n + m} (num ∘ suc ∘ toℕ)


Thank you very much for your answer. This fully solves my problem. It took me some time to adapt it to my original somewhat more involved problem, but tabulate did the trick in the end :)

It looks like you can generalize your function to an arbitrary index k so that recursion is no longer a problem:
rev-list2 : (m n k : ℕ) → List (idx k)
rev-list2 m zero    k = []
rev-list2 m (suc n) k = num (suc m) ∷ rev-list2 (suc m) n k

Then you can define your special case:
rev-list : (m n : ℕ) → List (idx (n + m))
rev-list m n = rev-list2 m n (n + m)


Thank you for your answer. This solves the described problem. However, it unfortunately does not solve my original problem in which (what I didn't mention) num also has a parameter that depends on the fixed k. I like your approach, because it's simple and easy to understand, but I will accept @effectfully 's answer as it is more general and also solves my original problem. (Probably I should have chosen a better example to illustrate the problem).

@user11718766 Sure! I actually suspected that your actual task was a little different and could not solved like this.
